Microsoft Edge remove the ClickOnce confirm window to "open this file"
We received a complaint from a user that they would like this window not to appear. ("Do you want to open this file?")

Is there a way for us, to tell Edge to open the .application without the need for an user action ?
If not, is there a way for the user to do that himself ?

Definitely nothing you can do from your end, short of a major bug in the browser. If the server could force a file to open without prompting, imagine the fun that malware authors would have!
